# Bash script [macOS Sierra Terminal] to create a .dmg for each subdirectory of a given one

Tags: bash, macos, shell, dmg

I want to create a script from terminal to be used like this one:

```
ddmg StartingDirectory
```

that will create into the StartingDirectory a dmg file for each subdirectory present.

Example:

```
\StartingDirectory
    \MDT1D01
    \MDT1D02
    \MDT1D03
    \MDT1DN
```

command should run for each subdirectory MDT1D0 (1..N)
and create a .dmg for each, with **VolumeName** and **FileName** as the name of the same subdirectory (that is MDT1D01 f.i.).
(**VolumeName** is the name that appears at the left side of the Finder when you open the dmg).

I already know that the command to create dmg is:

```
hdiutil create -volname VolumeName -srcfolder /path/to/the/folder/you/want/to/create -ov -format UDZO FileName.dmg
```

and this is working because I tested it.

I've already tried to create a personal command named dmg, in this way:

```
dmg(){
  hdiutil create -volname “$1” -srcfolder “$2” -ov -format UDZO “$3.dmg”
}
```

that should be used in this way:

```
dmg VolumeName source/directory/path FileName
```

but it doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why.

In addition I found a template to create scripts (this is working but it says I need to install xtools to work properly, I suppose because of the git command that I don't need right now):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Use set -x if you want to echo each command while getting executed
#set -x

#Save current directory so we can restore it later
cur=$PWD
#Save command line arguments so functions can access it
args=("$@")

#Put your code in this function
#To access command line arguments use syntax ${args[1]} etc
function dir_command {
    #This example command implements doing git status for folder
    cd $1
    echo "$(tput setaf 2)$1$(tput sgr 0)"
    git tag -a ${args[0]} -m "${args[1]}"
    git push --tags
    cd ..
}

#This loop will go to each immediate child and execute dir_command
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) | while read dir; do
   dir_command "$dir/"
done

#This example loop only loops through give set of folders    
declare -a dirs=("dir1" "dir2" "dir3")
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    dir_command "$dir/"
done

#Restore the folder
cd "$cur"
```

With these info, could you help me to create the script I need? 
I'm a newbie, so please be quite specific :)
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: When you say the `dmg` function "doesn't seem to work", what exactly does it do? Any error messages? One possible problem is the quotes: at least in the version you posted, it has fancy unicode quote marks (`“` and `”`) instead of plain ASCII quotes (`"`). The shell will not recognize unicode quotes.

Comment: It does NOTHING. No errors or whatelse. Btw, your it's a good point. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that.
This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Use set -x if you want to echo each command while getting executed
#set -x

#Save current directory so we can restore it later
cur=$PWD
#Save command line arguments so functions can access it
args=("$@")

#Put your code in this function
#This loop will go to each immediate child and execute hdiutil
find . -depth 1 -type d | cut -c 3- | while read dir; do
hdiutil create -volname $dir -srcfolder $dir -format UDZO $dir.dmg
done

#Restore the folder
cd "$cur"
```

Note that I've cut the "-ov" option to hdiutil, so it's not going to overwrite an existing dmg.

It's very useful because if you have a lot of subdirectories, it could happen that you get errors at some point (for instance I got the "resource busy" error), and in this way you can simply relaunch the command without worrying about what directory has got the error.
Just tested and it's working flawlessly. 5 hours it's creating dmgs right now :)